# Why is seeding the random generator not stable between versions of Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, seed

I am trying to reproduce a random sequence from python's `random.random()` on a different system with a different python3 version installed.

This should be easy as the [documentation says](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/random.html?highlight=random#notes-on-reproducibility):

> Most of the random module’s algorithms and seeding functions are
>   subject to change across Python versions, but two aspects are
>   guaranteed not to change:
>
> - If a new seeding method is added, then a backward compatible seeder
>     will be offered.
> - The generator’s random() method will continue to
>     produce the same sequence when the compatible seeder is given the same
>     seed.

So I expect the following code to print always the same 10 numbers, no matter the specific python3 version:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

from random import seed, random

seed(str(1))
for i in range(10):
    print(random())
```

However, testing it on two different machines:

```
3.2.3 (default, May  3 2012, 15:51:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
0.4782479962566343
0.044242767098090496
0.11703586901195051
0.8566892547933538
0.2926790185279551
0.0067328440779825804
0.0013279506360178717
0.22167546902173108
0.9864945747444945
0.5157002525757287
```

and

```
3.1.2 (release31-maint, Dec  9 2011, 20:59:40)  
[GCC 4.4.5]
0.0698436845523
0.27772471476
0.833036057868
0.35569897036
0.36366158783
0.722487971761
0.963133581734
0.263723867191
0.451002768569
0.0998765577881
```

Give different results.

Why is this? And is there any way to make this to work (i.e. get the same random sequence twice?)

Comment: for what it's worth, running your code snippet in 2.7 produces a completely different set of numbers than either of the two you posted.

Comment: It states *a backward compatible seeder will be offered* not that the existing method will be backward compatible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was looking through [What's New in Python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html) (because of this question), and I found:

> The random.seed() function and method *now* salt string seeds with an sha512 hash function. To access the previous version of seed in order to reproduce Python 3.1 sequences, set the version argument to 1, random.seed(s, version=1).

It appears to be a breaking change (from 3.1 to 3.2) with a backwards compatibility option.

(As borrible pointed out, because a compatible seeder *is* offered the documentation contract has not been violated.)

Comment: Thanks, this must be the problem. I must say that it is not very convenient that the version argument was not present yet in 3.1 :(

Comment: That applies when you use string seeds.  Unlike the OP, I'm seeding my random number generator with ints, and seeing different results. Incidentally, the getstate() method returns the same internal state, so it's not the seeding bit that changed, it's actual random nuumber generation.

Comment: Oh, actually I see random.random() produce the same sequence -- it's random.shuffle() and random.randrange() that produce different results on Python 3.1 and 3.2, even when given the same seed.  :-(

Answer (score 6):

The docs for `seed` say that they use the hash function to convert strings to valid input seeds.  When I tested various versions of Python2.X (don't have 3 installed at the moment), some versions gave different values for `hash(str(1))` Note that the docs for seed say that, regardless of version, they use the `hash` value for the string.  You might want to pass an int instead (in addition to @pst 's point about using the backwards-compatible version of seed).

Snippet from the [`random` module docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/random.html#random.seed) for 3.2:

> If x is an int, it is used directly.
>
> With version 2 (the default), a str, bytes, or bytearray object gets
>   converted to an int and all of its bits are used. With version 1, the
>   hash() of x is used instead.

(x here is the initializer for seed)