# fizzbuzz in Python using random, how does it work?

Tags: python, random-seed, fizzbuzz

I am having a hard time figuring out how the code below works:

```
import random

for i in range(0, 100):
    if not i % 15:
        random.seed(1178741599)
    print [i+1, "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz"][random.randint(0,3)]
```

I understand that when `i` is divisible by `15`, `random` will use the same `seed` and hence `randint(0, 3)` will always return the same index, but when I tried

```
for i in range(100):
    random.seed(1178741599)
    print random.randint(0,3) #always print 0
```

the above code always prints `0`, <s>shouldn't it be `3` (as the `"FizzBuzz"`'s index in list `[i+1, "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz"]`?</s>(this is the correct behavior, and corresponds to `i+1` in the list.)

And what about when `i` is divisible by `3` or `5`?

What is the magic of seed `1178741599`?

Edit: as jonrsharpe pointed out, the fizzbuzz code only works in python 2.x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
random.seed(n)
```

Means "reset the random number generator to some known position `n`". This means that the future outputs of the generator can be known in advance. It is useful for testing with the same "random" data over and over again.

What this code does is reset the generator every 15 steps, so you get the same sequence of 15 "random" integers (and, hence, of strings from the list) each time. In Python 2.x, the first "random" integer after the reset is always `0` (when I tried just now in Python 3, after `random.seed(1178741599)` I get `random.randint(0, 3) == 1`).

Note that this code *does not* do what a conventional FizzBuzz program does, and depends heavily on the `random` implementation. It works for me in 2.7.3 but *does not work* in 3.3.2 (see [Why is seeding the `random` number generator not stable between versions of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929701/why-is-seeding-the-random-generator-not-stable-between-versions-of-python)).

Comment: Now I have a better understanding. So because of the 'magic' of that particular seed, its first 15 random integers are exactly what fizzbuzz needs for picking up the right elements in `[i+1, "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz"]`. I guess you shouldn't get `1` since `i+1` has index `0`.

Comment: That's correct, but as I have just added it doesn't seem to work in Python 3.x

Comment: I just tried in Python 3.3, you are right, it always yields `1`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive way to go about finding the seed for your random number generator:

```
import random

expected = [0, 0, 1, 0, 2,
            1, 0, 0, 1, 2,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 3]

def is_working_seed(s):
    random.seed(s)
    return all(random.randint(0, 3) == e for e in expected)

seed = 0
while not is_working_seed(seed):
    seed += 1

print seed
```

<sup>(obviously, looping over all 2^32 values of seed is not a good plan)</sup>

Since there are `4**15 == 1073741824` ways to generate a list of random numbers in `0:4`, you'd expect there to be about 4 seeds in the space of 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Nice analysis for the seed, now I wonder if there is an efficient way or some theoretical approach to find the right seed...